# slow pipelight silverlight

Tags: 14.04, pipelight, moonlight

I've using Pipelight to stream Silverlight videos from one of the Polish sites: http://onet.tv. The vidoes are jerky though and can't keep up with the streaming. Any ideas how can I debug it? I'm using ubuntu 14.04, long support one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the site you provided supports also Flash and HTML5 (MSE). Is it mandatory for you to use Silverlight? Did you try out Google Chrome? I am using the Version 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit) and I'm able to play the videos without any problems without Pipelight. (Also works fine with Firefox 43.0).

If using Silverlight is mandatory, then according to the Pipelight [help page](http://pipelight.net/cms/faqs/faq-most-common-problems.html):

> A bad playback performance is almost always caused by either missing or broken 32 bit graphic drivers or some problems with pulseaudio. Many plugins synchronize the video output to the audio output (so that it does not get out of sync) and can cause extremely laggy playback if there is a problem with sound.

you should try out the solutions from the Pipelights help page first. E.g.: [Bad performance / Install 32 bit graphic driver files](http://pipelight.net/cms/faqs/faq-bad-performance-install-32-bit-graphic-driver-files.html).

You can also try to get the direct stream from your site and try to play it with VLC Player. Just install VLC, start the terminal and run:

```
vlc -vvv http://ecache4.m2d1.cdn.onet.pl/ceph/d15b4bf9-dff4-45d1-a39d-6d95f519e29e.1451738861.317688.mp4
```

I extracted the link to the MP4 file using developer tools of Google Chrome. You can do the same if the link isn't working anymore.
Also using `-vvv` option will tell VLC to print all kind of output messages. You should look for some warning or error messages like: picture is too late to be displayed etc. You can also check how many frames were lost by clicking Ctrl+I and going to the Statistics tab.

If the same problems appear using VLC you can be sure that this has nothing to do with your Pipelight plugin. I would then suggest to download  the video and try to play it offline:

```
wget http://ecache4.m2d1.cdn.onet.pl/ceph/d15b4bf9-dff4-45d1-a39d-6d95f519e29e.1451738861.317688.mp4
vlc -vvv d15b4bf9-dff4-45d1-a39d-6d95f519e29e.1451738861.317688.mp4
```

If the video plays without any problems now, then probably something is wrong with the TCP transmission. Here you can play around with Wireshark and `sudo sysctl -w ...` commands.

If the offline video playback is also lagging, then your system is either too slow, or badly configured.

I hope that I could help you a little bit.

Comment: I've solved my issue by using Chrome. Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll accept it :)